# An Equation about Continuous Linear Operators $T \overline{\text{span}(A)} = \overline{T\text{span}(A)}$ in Normed Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, let $T \in B(X,Y)$ where $B(X,Y)$ represents all continuous linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. $\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$ Let $A \subset X$ and $\span(A)$ is the smallest linear subspace which contains $A$. Prove that $T \overline{\span(A)} = \overline{T\span(A)}$.

Actually, I want the proof for $\overline{T\span(A)} \subset T \overline{\span(A)}  $, since the opposite direction can be easily obtained by the continuity and linearity of $T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true.  The range of a continuous linear operator in infinite-dimensional normed spaces is not necessarily closed.

Comment: I think you are right, but I am struggling with an example. Could please you provide a couterexample? Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(Tx)_n = x_n/n$ on $\ell^2$.